# Printing icons in the shell

Tags: python, icons

Below are some examples, when run inside the Python 3.4.3 Shell included in IDLE3 it will output special characters (icons). When I run this same code inside a terminal, the characters will not appear at all.

```
""" Some print functions with backslashes.
    In IDLE3 they will output 'special characters' or icons.
    In a terminal, they will not output anything. """

#Somtimes a visual effect.
print ("a, \a") #telephone
print ("\a")
print ("b, \b") #checkmark
print ("c, \c") # just a '\c' output.
# other letters like '\c' kept out the rest of this list.
print ("f, \f") #quarter note (musical)
print ("n, \n") #newline
print ("r, \r") #halve note (musical)
print ("t, \tTabbed in")
#print ("u, \u") #syntaxerror
print ("\u0000") #empty
print ("\u0001") #left arrow
print ("\u0002") #left arrow underline
print ("\u0003") #right arrow (play)
print ("v, \v") #eighth note (musical)
print ("\x01") # == '\u0001' __________(x == 00 ?)
print ("\1") # == '\u0001' == '\x01'

#some more fooling around
print ("\1") #left arrow
print ("\2") #underlined left arrow
print ("\3") #right arrow
print ("\4") #underlined right arrow
print ("\5") #trinity
print ("\6") #Q-parking
print ("\7") #telephone
print ("\8")
print ("\9")
print ("\10") #checkmark
print ("\11 hi") #tab
print ("\12 hi") #newline
print ("\13") #8th note
print ("\14") #4th note
print ("\15") #halve note
print ("\16") #whole note
print ("\17") #double 8th note
print ("\18")
print ("\19")
print ("\20") #left arrow (black)
print ("\21") #right arrow (black)
print ("\22") #harry potter
print ("\23") #X-chrom-carrying cell
print ("\24") #Y-chrom-carrying cell
print ("\25") #diameter for lefties
print ("\26") #pentoid
print ("\27") #gamma?
print ("\28") #I finally realised this will have to do with triple
              # binary per character? 111 = 7, stop = 8

print ("\30") #
print ("\31") # female
print ("\32") # male
print ("\33") #
print ("\34") # clock
print ("\35") # alfa / ichtus
print ("\36") # arc
print ("\37") # diameter

print ("\40hi") # spaces? I don't know. 


# This does not work by the way:

##import string

###No visual effect.
##alfa = string.ascii_lowercase
##for x in alfa:
##    print ("\%s" % x)
```

Some of my Python Shell 3.4.3. output in IDLE3:

[image: IDLE output]

Are these 'special' characters c.q. icons used in any way? Is there some documentation I could have read that would have prevented me from asking this question?

I checked on other questions about this issue on Stack, but all I found was people trying to pass in 'foreign' (like from word symbols or whatever) characters and make them get printed by Python.

Comment: Given that this question's about differing behaviour between IDLE and your terminal, *which terminal*?

Comment: Terminal Emulator in Ubuntu 14.
Kernel: 3.19.0-28-generic
Does this help?

Comment: Not all are printable characters, I imagine idle is not printing the output correctly

Comment: What font is your terminal using?

Comment: font: 'DejaVu Sans Mono Book'
font-size: '10'
encoding: 'utf-8'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in the IDLE and click "Options" and "Configure IDLE..." you see the font you are using. Fonts convert character numbers to what you see. A different font can produce different characters.

Example:

```
>>> print(u'\u2620')
☠
```

Which I looked for by searching ["unicode skull"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unicode+skull&t=opera&ia=answer) and which can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2620/index.htm).

Not all fonts support all characters.

Unicode characters are organized in [blocks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm) of a certain topic. I like the block ["Miscellaneous Symbols"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols/list.htm) where the skull is from.

## Encoding

Also an important question is which encoding you use. The encoding determines how characters are mapped to the [unicode blocks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm). A character has to go from `print(u'\0001')` to the `sys.stdout` to the console reading it and to the window manager. Each step only understands bytes - 256 possible characters.

So, there are various encodings, such as latin-1, which use the 256 possible characters and map them onto the unicode blocks. latin-1 uses the first two blocks, I think. There are encodings, such as UTF-8 which use 8 bits = 1 byte and more or utf-16 which uses 2 bytes and more or utf-32 which uses 4 bytes and more, which allow more characters to be transfered from the print through the different steps.

If I want to encode the skull and crossbones in latin-1 I would get this error:

```
>>> u'\u2620'.encode('latin-1')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    u'\u2620'.encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2620' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Another example where I encode the russian letter zhe in the cyrillic code page and the latin one:

```
>>> print u'\u0436', repr(u'\u0436'.encode('cp1251')) # cyrillic works
ж '\xe6'
>>> print u'\u0436', repr(u'\u0436'.encode('cp1252')) # latin-1 fails
ж

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    print u'\u0436', repr(u'\u0436'.encode('cp1252')) # latin-1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0436' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

To escape this encoding jungle, **use UTF-8** which can encode everything.

```
>>> print u'\u0436\u2620', repr(u'\u0436\u2620'.encode('utf-8'))
ж☠ '\xd0\xb6\xe2\x98\xa0'
```

Encoding and decoding with different encodings changes the character. If you want to use funny characters, use unicode and UTF-8.